# RIA Technology of Choice

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, silverlight, javafx, rich-internet-application

I'm looking into creating a Rich Internet Application. For the interface, I want something smooth, fast, and robust. I realize there are several technologies out there to do just that (Flex, standard HTML/Javascript, Silverlight).

After using Grooveshark, I am very impressed with its interface (written in Flex). Personally, I don't think I have seen an interface written in standard HTML/Javascript that is that visually stunning, smooth, and fast.

However, I have heard many arguments against using Flex with many believing Flash will *eventually* fade away.

Anyway, I have seen solid applications built with each, and I know a decision can depend on many things. But, in general, what are the pros/cons for each technology and which one would you ultimately choose for your RIA?

NOTE: This would be an open web application with the intended audience being anyone. It's not being built for specific client(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I would make the decision based upon my client(s).* For general "web stuff", I still am opposed to RIAs (I think they have more of a purpose in a rich client to a particular market, e.g. business -- or filling out online taxes returns -- and not general pleasure/browsing/navigating/site).

As far as Flash "fading away" -- haha. Yeah, right. We still have COBOL and Shockwave. A product with 99%+ market dominance (depends on market, of course) is hardly bound to "fade away" overnight. When the "eventual" does come, nobody will care about this next RIA project of yours anyway :-)

Comment: The fading away thing was mainly as a result of Apple/iPhone not adopting Flash, but now that thats back online with Adobe Air Packager for iPhone, its looking good again:)

Answer (score 1):

> with many believing Flash will eventually fade away

Sure, just like *any* technology, Flash will fade out at some time. But that won't happen in the near future, so it would be a stupid argument not to use Flash (in the same way you could stop developing things for »insert any technology here«).

I know this won't be a real answer as you want some more comparison of the current RIA technologies, but it is hard to do that anyway. In *some* way, you can build any application with *both* Flash and JavaScript. For more complex application *both* will require quite a lot customization to get the application running the way you want it. At that point Flash might have a small pro point given that you have a bit more powerful language with it than JavaScript (which still has performance problems depending on the browser, while Flash is more or less stable), and generally don't need to build anything on HTML's elements. But in the end, you can stil do it with both, so maybe you should decide based on your actual knowledge with the respective language instead (or base the decision on the client).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right in saying that Flex/Flash applications far outshine their HTML/JavaScript counterparts as far as UX is concerned. However, the main drawbacks are mobile and accessibility. Flash currently has poor reach on mobile platforms, but that shows signs of improving. Also I don't think most screen readers can deal with Flash. Silverlight is probably just as good, but it's not used as much and does not have nearly the user base of Flash.

Comment: Flash and Flex are 100% accessible and should work with screen readers.  However, the components that you're using need to be built to support this; and not all of them out in the wild will do out of the box.  So, while it is possible for Flash Apps to work with screen readers, you have to be careful about how you develop.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't think I have seen an interface
>   written in standard HTML/Javascript
>   that is that visually stunning.

I'm not a big fan of writing raw HTML/JavaScript because it's SO much effort to make it look as slick as some of the Adobe stuff.  However, there are some pretty decent frameworks and abstraction layers that let you get a visually stunning front-end, and let you write the while thing almost exclusively in Java.   I've had success with SmartClient/SmartGWT in the past to make an iGoogle-esque portlet web application.

Pros: Google Web Toolkit + Eclipse is free, don't have to write much raw HTML/JavaScript, saves a TON of dev time, aren't locked in to an Adobe product, GWT compiles to HTML+JavaScript and is absolutely universal

Cons: the high-end professional and enterprise versions are not particularly cheap (~2K USD)

Answer (score 0):

HTML+CSS+Javascript is a good solution. And maybe you should consider your RIA can across device and platform. Test some javascript framewoks first, especially those with RAD UI Tools, For example, [CrossUI](http://crossui.com).

Comment: This could probably be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: This question was asked over 3 years ago. The question is really old, and this answer doesn't really add much to help that.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, RIAs should migrate to full JavaScript UI with CSS skinning.
The task of building the UI should be analogous with these of the old tools like Visual Basic or Borland Delphi. This means almost entirely configuration instead of hand-writing the interface code.
You should also consider choosing a consistent widget set the follows the way of web components, i.e. inheriting from Element to always stay in sync with browser technology changes.
Here is a tool to help you evaluate several frameworks:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jul-designer/
Remember, following the standards and eventually anticipating them, is the best way to go.